# Filter a list of lists using list comprehension in Python

Tags: python-2.7, filtering, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists (shown below) that I would like to filter based on the first element of each lists.

```
raw_json = [[u'2014-09-09', u'18:00:00', 81, 1, u'codereview.stackexchange.com', u'Engineering & Technology', 1], [u'2014-09-09', u'18:00:00', 79, 1, u'google.com', u'Search', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 44, 1, u'newtab', u'Browsers', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 44, 1, u'iTunes', u'Music', -2], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 24, 1, u'google.com', u'Search', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 22, 1, u'effbot.org', u'Search', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 3, 1, u'spotify', u'General Entertainment', -2], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 2, 1, u'calendar.boston.com', u'Regional', -2]]
```

In short, I would like to be able to filter for todays date so ideally I would have returned to me that looks like this:

```
result = [[u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 44, 1, u'newtab', u'Browsers', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 44, 1, u'iTunes', u'Music', -2], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 24, 1, u'google.com', u'Search', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 22, 1, u'effbot.org', u'Search', 0], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 3, 1, u'spotify', u'General Entertainment', -2], [u'2014-09-11', u'23:00:00', 2, 1, u'calendar.boston.com', u'Regional', -2]]
```

I wrote the following code, but keep getting the error message saying `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

```
today = date.today().isoformat()
today_raw_json = [i for i in raw_json if today==raw_json[i][0]]
print today_raw_json
```

If someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Looping over a list loops over the elements, not the indices.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
[i for i in raw_json if i[0] == today]
```

The `i` is the actual element in the list, not its index.

Comment: Got it. So `i` was returning me the individual lists within my big list `raw_json` which accounted for the errors I was receiving. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in `filter` function. The syntax is:

```
filter(function, sequence)
```

So, your code would look like:

```
filter(lambda x:x[0] == today, raw_json)
```

P.S. I know you'd prefer to use list comprehensions, but I think a filter would make the code more readable here.